# Trust level reset after uploading new web.config

Tags: iis

I'm running a Windows 2008r2 server and I've set the default trust level of IIS to medium. However, one of my applications requires full trust so I've changed it in IIS. No problem so far, but when I upload a new web.config file the trust level is automatically changed to medium and my application doesn't work until I change it to full trust manually. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<trust level="Full" />` in your `web.config` in the `system.web` section:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <trust level="Full" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

When you make that change in IIS, it updates the `web.config` file. If you upload a new `web.config` without the trust level set, it will revert back to the default.